# How to determine a graph is totally connected?

Tags: matlab, graph-theory, complex-networks

Sorry for the simple question, but is there any way to determine a graph that is totally connected? I read some papers that indicate the total connectedness of a graph is the prerequisite of graph analysis. I search through some graph analysis toolboxes of Matlab for such function that determines the connectedness but it seems at least none is provided in these toolboxes. Could you please give me any suggestion on this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

you could do the following:

- assume G is the [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) for your graph
- build D which is a [diagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix) with the same size as G, put degree of Nth node in the Nth diagonal element
- make laplacian matrix via subtraction : L = D - G
- compute L's [eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors)(`eig` function in `matlab` will do it for you)
- the number of eigenvalues that are equal to zero is the number of connected components in the graph
- if the number of your components is 1 then your graph is fully connected , otherwise it has the number of components you wanted

---

this method works for both **directed** and **undirected** graphs

hope you find it helpful

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on graph theory but it looks like [`graphconncomp`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/bioinfo/ref/graphconncomp.html) will do the job.

This function finds all the connected components in a graph, so if the graph is fully connected it will return S=1 component, and C will contain a 1 for every node.

For example

```
[S,C] = graphconncomp(G)
if all(C==ones(size(C)))
  disp "G is fully connected";
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Stuart. I'm using Matlab 7.1(R14) and graphconncomp seems not present in this version. Maybe I should switch to R2013.

Comment: if you are working on directed graphs and you need the property of _connectedness_ and not _reachability_, make sure to use `graphconncomp(G, 'Weak', true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the FEX function `isconnected`, see [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19218-matgraph/content/matgraph/html/matgraph/@graph/isconnected.html).

This will determine if your graph is connected and has 1 as output if connected and 0 otherwise. Only works on undirected graphs though.